# Is there any way to mock Azure CloudQueueClient or CloudQueue?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, moq

I am writing unit tests for my code and have come across a method, which throws a StorageException when trying to Create a queue and AddMessage to the queue. I would like to test if the exception handling works fine. In order to do that I had an idea of using a mock for the CloudQueue, but later found out this class is sealed. Is there any way to test the exception handling (or force a StorageException) without actually changing the production code?

Comment: One way that I see is you would need to wrap the CloudQueue in an interface and then mock this interface to throw desired exception that you want to handle . But this would require your code to change. I don't see any other way.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about this method. However I don't want to refactor my code just for testing purposes. So I guess there is no way to cover those two outcomes, huh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have used the Microsoft Fakes framework to be able to unit test similar Azure SDK classes in the past. There is a little learning curve up front, but it works great.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it.

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way to handle this is with an Interface around a `CloudQueueClient` (which is what @tyrion) suggested, above .. but also an interface for a `ICloudQueue`

```
public interface ICloudQueueClientWrapper
{
    ICloudQueueWrapper GetQueueReference(string queueName);
}

// ----------------

public class CloudQueueClientWrapper : ICloudQueueClientWrapper
{
    private readonly Lazy<CloudQueueClient> _cloudQueueClient;

    public CloudQueueClientWrapper(string connectionStringName)
    {
        connectionStringName.ShouldNotBeNullOrWhiteSpace();

        _cloudQueueClient = new Lazy<CloudQueueClient>(() =>
        {
            // We first need to connect to our Azure storage.
            var storageConnectionString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting(connectionStringName);
            var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);

            // Create the queue client.
            return storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();
        });
    }

    public ICloudQueueWrapper GetQueueReference(string queueName)
    {
        queueName.ShouldNotBeNullOrWhiteSpace();

        var cloudQueue = _cloudQueueClient.Value.GetQueueReference(queueName);
        return new CloudQueueWrapper(cloudQueue);
    }

    // Add more methods here which are a one-to-one match against the underlying CQC.
}
```

So that's the first interface and wrapper ... and notice this returns an `ICloudQueue` instance .. so lets do that now...

```
public interface ICloudQueueWrapper
{
    Task AddMessageAsync(CloudQueueMessage message);
}

public class CloudQueueWrapper : ICloudQueueWrapper
{
    private readonly CloudQueue _cloudQueue;

    public CloudQueueWrapper(CloudQueue cloudQueue)
    {
        cloudQueue.ShouldNotBeNull();

        _cloudQueue = cloudQueue;
    }

    public async Task AddMessageAsync(CloudQueueMessage message)
    {
        message.ShouldNotBeNull();

        await _cloudQueue.AddMessageAsync(message);
    }
}
```

Ok ... so now lets try using this in some unit test :)

```
    [Theory]
    [MemberData(nameof(StockIds))]
    public async Task GivenSomeData_DoFooAsync_AddsDataToTheQueue(string[] stockIds)
    {
        // Arrange.
        var cloudQueue = Mock.Of<ICloudQueueWrapper>();
        var cloudQueueClient = Mock.Of<ICloudQueueClientWrapper>();
        Mock.Get(cloudQueueClient).Setup(x => x.GetQueueReference(It.IsAny<string>()))
            .Returns(cloudQueue);
        var someService = new SomeService(cloudQueueClient);

        // Act.
        await someService.DoFooAsync(Session);

        // Assert.
        // Did we end up getting a reference to the queue?
        Mock.Get(cloudQueueClient).Verify(x => x.GetQueueReference(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once);

        // Did we end up adding something to the queue?
        Mock.Get(cloudQueue).Verify(x => x.AddMessageAsync(It.IsAny<CloudQueueMessage>()), Times.Exactly(stockids.Length));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution by @Pure.Krome is a good way to do it - I would just like to pinpoint one possible issue with his implemenentation of `CloudQueueClientWraper`:

```
public class CloudQueueClientWrapper : ICloudQueueClientWrapper
{
    private readonly Lazy<CloudQueueClient> _cloudQueueClient;

    public CloudQueueClientWrapper(string connectionStringName)
    {
        connectionStringName.ShouldNotBeNullOrWhiteSpace();

        _cloudQueueClient = new Lazy<CloudQueueClient>(() =>
        {
            // We first need to connect to our Azure storage.
            var storageConnectionString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting(connectionStringName);
            var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);

            // Create the queue client.
            return storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();
        });
    }

    public ICloudQueueWrapper GetQueueReference(string queueName)
    {
        queueName.ShouldNotBeNullOrWhiteSpace();

        var cloudQueue = _cloudQueueClient.Value.GetQueueReference(queueName);
        return new CloudQueueWrapper(cloudQueue);
    }

    // Add more methods here which are a one-to-one match against the underlying CQC.
}
```

`Lazy<T>` caches exceptions! So if an attempt from one thread (or rather `Task`) to create the `.Value` by executing `valueFactory` delegate fails with Exception, all subsequent calls to the `.Value` will return that same Exception.

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1?view=netframework-4.8) say:

> Exception caching When you use factory methods, exceptions are cached. That is, if the factory method throws an exception the first time a thread tries to access the Value property of the Lazy object, the same exception is thrown on every subsequent attempt. This ensures that every call to the Value property produces the same result and avoids subtle errors that might arise if different threads get different results. The Lazy stands in for an actual T that otherwise would have been initialized at some earlier point, usually during startup. A failure at that earlier point is usually fatal. If there is a potential for a recoverable failure, we recommend that you build the retry logic into the initialization routine (in this case, the factory method), just as you would if you weren't using lazy initialization.

As a "workaround" - ditch the built-in `Lazy<T>` and implement your own. One elegant way of doing it is suggested at [this](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/32337#issuecomment-498962755) GitHub issue by @mariusGundersen

```
public class AtomicLazy<T>
{
    private readonly Func<T> _factory;

    private T _value;

    private bool _initialized;

    private object _lock;

    public AtomicLazy(Func<T> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public AtomicLazy(T value)
    {
        _value = value;
        _initialized = true;
    }

    public T Value => LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref _value, ref _initialized, ref _lock, _factory);
}
```